# Howto make numpy ndarray.tobytes() return bytes in python 2.7

Tags: python, string, numpy, byte

I have two python versions installed on ubuntu 14.04:

- PV1) 2.7.6
- PV2) 3.4

Both installations have numpy at version 1.10.4

When running

```
arr = np.random.randint(0,255,(3,3))
type(arr.tobytes())
```

I get `str` for PV1 and `bytes` for PV2.

What I need is to get bytes in both installations.
How can I achieve that without programming, but rather up/downgrading something?

The point is that the `.tobytes()` call is in some 3rd party module and I would like to avoid modifying this code.

Thanks in advance,

werpoi

Comment: So, if I'm understand correctly, you have an installation of Python 2.7 and an installation of Python 3.4, and the behavior of ndarray.tobytes() is different? I would recommend running the same version of Python on both, so you don't have to worry about code incompatibility then.

Comment: Why are you mixing both python2 and 3? The str type is also very different in python2 vs python3, bytes is an alias for str in python2.

Comment: str in python 2.7 is the same as bytes in python 3.

Comment: The `python2.7` version should be returning the same thing.  It just calls it `str` and doesn't use the `b` flag.

Comment: As best I can tell, this `tobytes` is the same as `tostring` in earlier numpy versions.  I found it useful to play with these functions, and `np.fromstring` in Ipython sessions running the 2 Python versions.